# How to store current route ID within a View from the URL into a new variable (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to store the ID from route A ex. /{aController}/{aAction}/{aID} so that I can 
use aID to make an ActionLink on the same view that will redirect me to Route B --->/{bController}/{bAction}/{bID}

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create", "bCreate", "bView", new {bID=aID})
```

Is this idea correct? And how can I store the ID of Route ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to get the id in your view:

```
@{
    var aID = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"];
 }
```

Then you can use that to call your method:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create", "bCreate", "bView", new {bID=aID})
```